# "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature" error when combining normal and ...rest function parameters

Tags: typescript, overloading

I am trying to create types for my fork of [strformat function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strformat). This function takes a string, and an **optional** list of interpolated varibables, defined in one of three ways (each having its overload):

- `strformat('{foo} {bar}', {foo: "abc", bar: "def" })` - a dictionary of all variables and their values
- `strformat('{0} {1}', ["abc", "def"])` - an array of variables
- `strformat('{0} {1}', "abc", "def")` -  a list of variables in spread into individual arguments

This seems to be a natural way of typing this function:

```js
type VariableValue = string | number | boolean | null | undefined
type VariableDefinition = VariableValue | (() => VariableValue)

type ArrayVariableDefinition = VariableDefinition[]
type ObjectVariableDefinition = Record<string, VariableDefinition>

function strformat(str: string,  args?: ObjectVariableDefinition): string
function strformat(str: string,  args?: ArrayVariableDefinition): string
function strformat(str: string,  ...args: ArrayVariableDefinition): string
function strformat(str: string, ...args: ([ArrayVariableDefinition] | [ObjectVariableDefinition] | ArrayVariableDefinition)): string {
    return "9"
}
```

But I keep getting this error on the first two overloads, without any additional explaination:

> This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature

I also tried this for the implementation signature, but it's still not compatible with the second overload:

```js
function strformat(str: string, firstArg?: VariableDefinition | ObjectVariableDefinition, ...restArgs: ArrayVariableDefinition): string
```

What am I doing wrong, how do I type this properly? [Here is a playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mb3z8W)

Comment: It should be `[ArrayVariableDefinition]`, not just `[VariableDefinition]`, no? Also I think it has something to do with `?` allowing `undefined`. https://tsplay.dev/wO2pMW

Comment: You don't need the second argument to be optional anyways, since the last overload will cover that: https://tsplay.dev/mLJBKw

Comment: @kelsny Oh wow, so it really was just a silly mistake like that. Thank you very much!